# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition fails on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, geolocation

This works on `Safari` on `Mac OS X`, and `Chrome` on both `Mac OS X` and `Android`.
But it fails on `Safari` on `iOS` (tested on both `iPhone 8` and `iPad`).

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  alert('geolocation OK');
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    alert('getCurrentPosition OK');
    BaseLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    initMap();
  });
}
```

I am getting the alert `geolocation OK`, but the second `getCurrentPosition OK` doesn't show on `iOS` and `initMap` is never called.

How do I debug, I do not have a USB cable to connect my `iPhone` or `iPad`.

Comment: Check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50424843/navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-not-triggering-in-ios-simulator-with-re

Comment: Seems to solve it, yes. Thank you. Make answer?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but we had some major issues at work with `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` in `standalone` mode in iOS Safari.

I posted a more comprehensive answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67924991/navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-hangs-on-ios-pwa/67924992#67924992) but the general gist of our final code was:

```
export function getUserPosition(): Promise<GeolocationPosition> {
  const promiseArray = [];

  if (navigator.standalone) {
    promiseArray.push(
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const wait = setTimeout(() => {
          clearTimeout(wait);
          reject('Location has timed out');
        }, 4000);
      })
    );
  }

  const getCurrentPositionPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject, {
        timeout: 5000,
        maximumAge: 2000,
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
      });
    } else {
      reject(new Error('Browser does not support geolocation!'));
    }
  });

  promiseArray.push(getCurrentPositionPromise);

  return Promise.race(promiseArray) as Promise<GeolocationPosition>;
}
```